# How could I fix this iframe bug with header

Tags: html, css, image, iframe, bootstrap-4

EDIT: I fixed it by myself! If you get this same problem, follow this:

from

```
nav {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
```

to

```
nav {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 10;
}
```

I'm making responsive website design. I use bootstrap 4. So, I have navigation menu and I have iframe and img tags in one section. When I scroll the page to the bottom, iframe shows on the header. the header is sticky, so that's why the iframe is supposed to be under the header. I'll show you a gif now... https://i.imgur.com/4ZMCTsN.gifv
Feel free to ask more css/html code sections, I'll let you know with them.

I've tried to set header (nav menu)'s z-index to highest possible & change nav menu's display tag to block but it just ruins everything.

```
<style>
/* the entire header thing is in external .css file, I just put this here 
to show you guys */
nav {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
</style> 

                    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active">
                        <h4><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>&nbsp;Our Location <small>More like our favourite surf spot</small></h4>

                        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d6048.676068967504!2d-73.96889056972904!3d40.710574467186305!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c25bd9abcea3c7%3A0x34a2832eedb859d8!2sGiando+on+the+Water!5e0!3m2!1sfi!2sfi!4v1550400186363" width="100%" height="200" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>  
                    </div>
```

Comment: If you figured out the answer, you can answer your question yourself and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!  If anyone else has this same problem, change it...

from

```
nav {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
```

to

```
nav {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 10;
}
```